# Coinpunk / Bitcoind / OSX Running on local machine error

Tags: macos, bitcoin, bitcoind

Good day.
Installation process and configuration of bitcoind, coinpunk and redis went good, according to this guide: https://github.com/kyledrake/coinpunk/blob/master/docs/INSTALL-OSX.md
After all i'm launching all the procedures through OSX terminal:

```
$bitcoind &
$cd coinpunk
$redis-server
$node start.js
```

Got no errors. Then i go to my localhost:8080 and Coinpunk successfully launches. But after trying to Sign Up, for creating new account and wallet i get the error:

> **Received an unrecognized error from the bitcoin server**

And the terminal message:

```
bitcoind error 500: {"code":-5,"message":"InvalidÂ BitcoinÂ address"}
bitcoind error 500: {"code":-5,"message":"InvalidÂ BitcoinÂ address"}
```

I checked all my config files for matching between npcuser and npcpassword. Got no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that both config files in `coinpunk/config.json` and in `coinpunk/public/config.json` are configured for testnet or for production.

1. coinpunk/config.json

   - For testnet: `"testnet": true,`
   - For production delete the above line if its there.
2. coinpunk/public/config.json

   - For testnet: `"network": "testnet",`
   - For production : `"network": "prod",`

In case that doesn't fix the problem. You can't mix redis databases from testnet and production, so if you already used testnet and want to switch to production you should delete/move your old `dump.rdb`. In Linux it's located in `/var/lib/redis/dump.rdb` not sure about OSX.

Source: https://github.com/kyledrake/coinpunk/issues/87